# Accessing codebehind field values through ASP.NET HTML code

Tags: c#, asp.net

simple question

in code behind(.cs) we have

```
string error="11000114S";
```

in ASP (.aspx) we have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" AutoPostBack="false"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="textValidator" runat="server" controlToValidate="text"
errormessage=(our string error="11000114S")>
```

So how to do this, assign value from cs-> saved error list to html ?

Comment: I would NOT suggest reffer code behind from View, try to keep a View decoupled from code behind as much as possible, just initialize error message in code behind itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as adding this to your .cs  .. if I understand you correctly

```
string error="11000114S";
textValidator.ErrorMessage = error ; // or what ever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
protected string error="11000114S";

<asp:TextBox ID="text" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" AutoPostBack="false"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="textValidator" runat="server" controlToValidate="text"
errormessage='<%# error %>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign error messages dynamically to your validators in your code behind. I.e.:

```
this.textValidator.ErrorMesssage = error;
```